# Call Function After a specific intervel

Tags: c#

I'm trying to call a function at a regular interval.

The code below is written in the `global.asax.cs` file and it's working is `ScheduleTaskTrigger()` calls `CheckLicenseExpiry()` after **1 min**. But I also want to call this function every , let's say **4 hrs**.

is there anyway for achieving this by changing this code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //used here formating API//
        HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

        ScheduleTaskTrigger();
    }
    static void ScheduleTaskTrigger()
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("ScheduledTaskTrigger",
                              string.Empty,
                              null,
                              Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
            //  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), // Every 1 hour
            // TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.0167),
                              TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                              CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
                              new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CheckLicenseExpiry));
    }

    static void CheckLicenseExpiry(string key, Object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
        CompanyHelper.CheckLicenseExpired();
    }
```

Comment: I'm doing this in MVC

Comment: My answer below should also work in MVC

Comment: try add ssis proj to your solution, then create a job on ssms

Comment: my database is not sql,its mongodb

Comment: I noticed all the answers have a vote, but there are no accepted ones :p

Comment: @Rariolu becoz i didnt get answer from any,and upvote for showing thanks for those show interest for helping me

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use Windows Forms, use the "Timer" class.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

//[...]

Timer timer;
private void Initialiser()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 3600000;//Set interval to an hour in the form of milliseconds.
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
}
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //The function you wish to do every hour.
}
```

You can change the interval to anything given that it is in the form of milliseconds (1000 per second). (e.g. 1 minute: 60000, 4 hours: 14400000).

P.S You can just use the "System.Windows.Forms" library without necessarily having a Windows Forms program, I imagine you could use this code in WPF also).

Comment: I'm doing this in MVC

Comment: Also, from the docs "This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and *must be used in a window*." IIRC, I think that is because it needs a UI thread to marshal the actions onto when it ticks. See link here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Baldrick I just got it to work in a Console Application without a Form, if it can work there it can work here.

Comment: @Rariolu: Maybe it works for you in that case, but if the MS docs for the class say it's not supported, it's probably a bad idea. Works now does not mean works always or works predictably... ;)

Comment: @Baldrick yes, that doesn't mean it isn't worth a try though as no part of this directly links to a dependence on a windows form.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `System.Threading.Timer`([MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)). It provides a mechanism for executing a method at specified intervals and does not depends on platform:

```
new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
    {
        // do something here
    }, 
    null, 
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) /*dueTime*/, 
    TimeSpan.FromHours(1) /*period*/
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I read from your sample, you want to check whether a license has expired on a regular basis. Solving this using the ASP.NET cache - which might work but maybe not in all scenarios (ASP.NET cache was built for a different purpose). Also, using timers is not a good idea as the application pool of the web application might not be running thus the task will not be executed.

Instead you could check on each request whether the license has expired. In order to save performance, you could only check if the last check was done more than 4 hours ago.

In ASP.NET MVC you can create an ActionFilter or AuthorizationFilter that implements this logic. You can apply this filter either globally to all routes or only to specific routes/controllers/actions.

As you want to block access to your site if the check is not successful, a custom AuthorizationFilter is a good approach. For details on ActionFilters, see this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs), for a sample on implementing a custom AuthorizationFilter, see this [link](http://yassershaikh.com/custom-authorization-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-iauthorizationfilter-filterattribute/).

In the filter, you should be aware that there can be parallel requests that access the variable that stores the time of the last check. So you need to lock the resources in a appropriate way.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

Global.asax

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scheduler.Start();
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scheduler.Stop();
    }
}
```

Scheduler.cs (helper class)

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

public class Scheduler
{
    private static IScheduler _scheduler;

    public static void Start()
    {
        _scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        _scheduler.Start();

        ITrigger myTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInHours(4)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        IJobDetail myJob = JobBuilder.Create<MyJobClass>().Build();
        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(myJob, myTrigger);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        if (_scheduler != null)
        {
            _scheduler.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

MyJobClass.cs

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class MyJobClass : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.